# What do the letters mean in sandpaper grading?

Tags: materials, sanding, grinder

I have a set of sandpapers that has the following papers:

```
 60 AN
100 GB
120 DN
180 FB
```

All have the marking `S/C/W/P paper T9 C Closed`. These are all paper sheets. I know that the number is the grain size.

What do the other markings mean?

Especially the `100 GB`. I've noticed that it behaves somewhat different to its grit size compared to the others. I am guessing that the G means its the thickest paper? The backside looks different compared to others.

Comment: The Googles! They do nothing!  -- My best guess is that they're manufacturer specific codes regarding backing and abrasive type.  I could find no standards other than three different grit standards.

Comment: what industry is the paper made for (metal, wood, other)?

Comment: @paperstreet It says that its an assortment of waterproof and "Sanding Sheets for Aluminum, Soft Metals, and Nonmetals". I also found out that letters A to F are rigidness of the packing. This seems to make sense as paper marked with "AN" is the most flexible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php?title=Sandpaper):

> The weight of the backing is usually designated by a letter. For paper backings, the weight ratings range from "A" to "F," with A designating the lightest and F the heaviest. Letter nomenclature follows a different system for cloth backings, with the weight of the backing rated J, X, Y , T, and M, from lightest to heaviest.